# How to add an </div> in order to separate two different elements with different class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want my website to generate a table of contents using the information inside a div with the id "contents". The html has this structure:

```html
  <div id="contents" class="iceberg_content_text">
    <h1>Title (Shouldn't be in the ToC)</h1>
    <h2 class="">H2 number 1</h2>
    <h3 class="">foo1.1</h3>
    <h3 class="">foo1.2</h3>
    <h2 class="">H2 number 2 </h2>
    <h3 class="">foo2.1</h3>
    <h4>h4 foo2.1.1(shouldn't be in ToC)</h4>
    <h5>h5 foo2.1.1.1 (shouldn't be in ToC)</h5>
    <p>p foo</p>
  </div>
```

And I want to make this table of contents structure. I know it's a little weird for a table of contents, but I have made my own css style that works using this structure:

```html
<div class="H2_number_1">
   <a class="list-group-item" href="#toc-item-1">foo1.1</a>
   <a class="list-group-item" href="#toc-item-2">foo1.2</a>
</div>
<div class="H2_number_2_">
   <a class="list-group-item" href="#toc-item-4">foo2.1</a>
</div>
```

However, the actual result is:

```html
<div class="H2_number_1">
    <a class="list-group-item" href="#toc-item-1">foo1.1</a>
    <a class="list-group-item" href="#toc-item-2">foo1.2</a>
    <div class="H2_number_2_">
        <a class="list-group-item" href="#toc-item-4">foo2.1</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside this code snippet is the JS code that I'm using. I'm using JQuery 3.5.1, you can use other libraries if you need to.

```js
$(document).ready(function toc_builder() {


  var children = $("#contents").children('H2, H3');

  var html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    $(children[i]).prop('id', 'toc-item-' + i); //adds ids to children to be hooked with the link below
    if ($(children[i]).prop('tagName') == 'H2') {
      html += "<div class=\"" + $(children[i]).html().replace(/ /g, "_") + "\">" + "" + "</a>";
    } else if ($(children[i]).prop('tagName') == 'H3') {
      html += "<a class=\"list-group-item\" href=\"#toc-item-" + i + "\">" + $(children[i]).html() + "</a>";
    };
  }
  $("#toc").html(html);


});
```

```css
.H2_number_1 a {
  color: yellow;
}

.H2_number_2 a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="toc">
    enable JS!!
  </div>
  <h1>DONT DELETE ME!</h1>
  <div id="contents" class="iceberg_content_text">
    <h1>Title (Shouldn't be in the ToC)</h1>
    <h2 class="">H2 number 1</h2>
    <h3 class="">foo1.1</h3>
    <h3 class="">foo1.2</h3>
    <h2 class="">H2 number 2 </h2>
    <h3 class="">foo2.1</h3>
    <h4>h4 foo2.1.1(shouldn't be in ToC)</h4>
    <h5>h5 foo2.1.1.1 (shouldn't be in ToC)</h5>
    <p>p foo</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

I know I haven't added any "" inside the js code, the thing is I don't know how can I modify the code in order to create the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you start a new DIV, you need to close the previous one. Check if the HTML is empty to know if there's already a previous DIV to close.

You also had an extra space at the end of `<h2 class="">H2 number 2 </h2>`, so it wasn't matching the CSS class.

```js
$(document).ready(function toc_builder() {
  var children = $("#contents").children('H2, H3');

  var html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    $(children[i]).prop('id', 'toc-item-' + i); //adds ids to children to be hooked with the link below
    if ($(children[i]).prop('tagName') == 'H2') {
      if (html) { // close the previous H2 DIV if any
        html += "</div>";
      }
      html += "<div class=\"" + $(children[i]).html().replace(/ /g, "_") + "\">" + "" + "</a>";
    } else if ($(children[i]).prop('tagName') == 'H3') {
      html += "<a class=\"list-group-item\" href=\"#toc-item-" + i + "\">" + $(children[i]).html() + "</a>";
    };
  }
  $("#toc").html(html);


});
```

```css
.H2_number_1 a {
  color: yellow;
}

.H2_number_2 a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="toc">
    enable JS!!
  </div>
  <h1>DONT DELETE ME!</h1>
  <div id="contents" class="iceberg_content_text">
    <h1>Title (Shouldn't be in the ToC)</h1>
    <h2 class="">H2 number 1</h2>
    <h3 class="">foo1.1</h3>
    <h3 class="">foo1.2</h3>
    <h2 class="">H2 number 2</h2>
    <h3 class="">foo2.1</h3>
    <h4>h4 foo2.1.1(shouldn't be in ToC)</h4>
    <h5>h5 foo2.1.1.1 (shouldn't be in ToC)</h5>
    <p>p foo</p>
  </div>
</body>
```